# Is it possible to have 0 discriminant of elements in a ring?

Tags: ring-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory

Given a a ring $B$ and a subring $A$, where $B$ is a free $A$-module of rank $n$, if $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ two $A$-bases for $K$ we have $disc(x_1, \dots, x_n) = \det(a_{ij})^2disc(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ where $a_{ij}$ comes from the equalities

$y_i =\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n{a_{ij}x_j}$, provided that $a_{ij}\in A$.

I saw without proof that the matrix $(a_{ij})$ is invertible. I tried to prove this claim but could not find a way to do it. How can I prove it, or what can we say if $\det(a_{ij})=0?$

Answer (score 0):

It comes from the fact that both $y_i$ and $x_j$ are bases.

Since the $x_j$ form a basis, we can write, as you've done,
$$y_i = \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j$$
for each $i$. But the $y_i$ form a basis, so for each $j$, we can write 
$$x_j = \sum_{i=k}^n b_{jk}y_k,\quad b_{jk}\in A$$

and hence
$$y_i = \sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j=\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}b_{jk}y_k,$$
from which it's clear that $a_{ij}b_{jk}=\delta_{ik}$ - i.e. $(a_{ij})$ has inverse $(b_{jk})$.

Alternatively, you can see that if $(a_{ij})$ has determinant $0$, then $\mathrm{disc}(x_1,\ldots, x_n) = 0$, which means that the $x_i$ are linearly dependent.

Comment: How do we conclude from $a_{ij}b_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$ that the matrix $(a_{ij})$ is invertible?

Comment: In the usual notation that is just $AB =I$ - i.e. $(b_{jk})$ is the inverse of $(a_{ij})$.

Comment: So the $\delta$ is Kroenecker's delta?